# java | combine some lists of different object types by timestamp

Tags: java, java-ee-8

I am looking for a way to combine several lists with objects of different types. The target fields should be specified using annotations on the target object. My biggest problem is taking into account the timestamps, which represent the validity of the individual objects in relation to time. Each source object must have implemented these timestamps (from and to). I ensure this using an interface.

The following example should best illustrate my project:

data list object TestObjectA

```
01.01.2020 | 31.01.2020 | FieldAData1
01.02.2020 | 30.04.2020 | FieldAData2
01.05.2020 | 31.05.2020 | FieldAData3
```

data list object TestObjectB

```
01.02.2020 | 31.03.2020  | FieldBData1
01.04.2020 | [open] null | FieldBData2
```

data list object TestObjectC

```
01.06.2020 | 31.07.2020  | FieldCData1
01.08.2020 | [open] null | FieldCData2
```

result list

```
01.01.2020 | 31.01.2020  | FieldAData1 | null        | null
01.02.2020 | 31.03.2020  | FieldAData2 | FieldBData1 | null
01.04.2020 | 30.04.2020  | FieldAData2 | FieldBData2 | null
01.05.2020 | 31.05.2020  | FieldAData3 | FieldBData2 | null
01.06.2020 | 31.07.2020  | null        | FieldBData2 | FieldCData1
01.08.2020 | [open] null | null        | FieldBData2 | FieldCData2
```

my source code

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface DataMappingConfig {
    Class<? extends TimeRangeData> sourceType();
    String sourceFieldName();
}

public interface TimeRangeData {
    public Calendar getFrom();
    public Calendar getTo();
}

public interface TimeRangeResult {

    public Calendar getFrom();
    public void setFrom(Calendar from);

    public Calendar getTo();
    public void setTo(Calendar to);
}

public class TestResultItem implements TimeRangeResult {

    private Calendar from;
    private Calendar to;

    @DataMappingConfig(sourceType = TestClassA.class, sourceFieldName = "fielNameA")
    private String dataFieldA;

    @DataMappingConfig(sourceType = TestClassB.class, sourceFieldName = "fielNameB")
    private String dataFieldB;

    @DataMappingConfig(sourceType = TestClassC.class, sourceFieldName = "fielNameC")
    private String dataFieldC;

    public Calendar getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(Calendar from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Calendar getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(Calendar to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getDataFieldA() {
        return this.dataFieldA;
    }

    public String getDataFieldB() {
        return this.dataFieldB;
    }

    public String getDataFieldC() {
        return this.dataFieldC;
    }
}

public class TestClassA implements TimeRangeData {

    private Calendar from;
    private Calendar to;
    private String fielNameA;

    /*
    [...]
    */

    public TestClassA(Calendar from, Calendar to, String data) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.fielNameA= data;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    public String getFielNameA() {
        return this.fielNameA;
    }

    /*
    [...]
    */
}

public class TestClassB implements TimeRangeData {

    private Calendar from;
    private Calendar to;
    private String fielNameB;

    /*
    [...]
    */

    public TestClassB(Calendar from, Calendar to, String data) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.fielNameB= data;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    public String getFielNameB() {
        return this.fielNameB;
    }

    /*
    [...]
    */
}

public class TestClassC implements TimeRangeData {

    private Calendar from;
    private Calendar to;
    private String fielNameC;

    /*
    [...]
    */

    public TestClassC(Calendar from, Calendar to, String data) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.fielNameC= data;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getFrom() {
        return this.from;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getTo() {
        return this.to;
    }

    public String getFielNameC() {
        return this.fielNameC;
    }

    /*
    [...]
    */
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public List<T extends TimeRangeResult> joinData(Class<T> targetType, List<? extends TimeRangeData> ... datas){
    /*
    [ searched code ]
    */
}
```

Is there a possibility in Java to combine the data as I have shown in the example?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve my aims by using stream and lambda?

Answer (score 0):

I thin you can concat these list's on three ways.

You can use simple for each loop

```
public List<TimeRangeData> createConcatedList(List<TimeRangeData> ... datas){
        List<TimeRangeData> out = new ArrayList();
        for(List<TimeRangeData> data: datas){
            out.addAll(data);
        }
        
        return out;
        
    }
```

Or you can convert array to the list and then stream it.

```
public List<TimeRangeData> createConcatedList(List<TimeRangeData> ... datas){
    List<TimeRangeData> out = new ArrayList();
    
    Arrays.asList(datas).stream().forEach(i-> out.addAll(i));
    
    return out;
    
}
```

Or you can change your method that it can take List of Lists as argument.

```
public List<TimeRangeData> createConcatedList(List<List<TimeRangeData>> datas){
    List<TimeRangeData> out = new ArrayList();
    
    datas.stream().forEach(i-> out.addAll(i));
    
    return out;
    
}
```

But if you want to create a list of TimeRangeResult objects I think the simplest way is change TimeRangeData to abstract class and add method which creates String key. Then you can simple create Map of keys. This Map will be distinct. Now you must iterate trough this Map and in every datas list you should search for this key.

```
abstract class TimeRangeData {

        public abstract Calendar getFrom();

        public abstract Calendar getTo();
        
        public String getKey(){
            return String.valueOf(getFrom().getTimeInMillis())+ String.valueOf(getTo().getTimeInMillis());
        }
    }

    public List<TimeRangeResult> createConcatedList(Class<T> targetType, List<TimeRangeData>... datas) {
    List<TimeRangeResult> out = new ArrayList();
    HashMap<String, List<Calendar>> keys = new HashMap();
    
    datas[0].stream().forEach(i -> keys.put(i.getKey(), Arrays.asList(i.getFrom(), i.getTo())));
    datas[1].stream().forEach(i -> keys.put(i.getKey(), Arrays.asList(i.getFrom(), i.getTo())));
    datas[2].stream().forEach(i -> keys.put(i.getKey(), Arrays.asList(i.getFrom(), i.getTo())));
    
    keys.entrySet().stream().forEach(i -> {
        TimeRangeResult tmp = new TimeRangeResult();
        Map.Entry<String, List<Calendar>> key = i;
        TimeRangeData a;
        TimeRangeData b;
        TimeRangeData c;
        
        tmp.setFrom(key.getValue().get(0));
        tmp.setTo(key.getValue().get(1));
        
        a = datas[0].stream().filter(i2->i2.getKey().equals(key.getKey())).findFirst().orElse(null);
        b = datas[1].stream().filter(i2->i2.getKey().equals(key.getKey())).findFirst().orElse(null);
        c = datas[2].stream().filter(i2->i2.getKey().equals(key.getKey())).findFirst().orElse(null);
        
        tmp.setA(a == null? null : a.toString());
        tmp.setB(b == null? null : b.toString());
        tmp.setC(c == null? null : c.toString());
        
        out.add(tmp);
        
    });

    return out;

}
```